# How do I get uid of a File Reference Object in TYPO3?

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions, fal

I am trying to get a file through this code `$f = $resourceFactory->getFileObject($uid);` but the problem is the `uid` is a protected field in the file reference object, as seen below so I am not able to get the `uid`, and `getUid()` obviously wont work either.

So how can I get the uid of the file reference (FAL)

```
/**
* A file reference object (File Abstraction Layer)
*
* @api experimental! This class is experimental and subject to change!
*/
class FileReference extends 
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\AbstractFileFolder
{
  /**
  * Uid of the referenced sys_file. Needed for extbase to serialize the
  * reference correctly.
  *
  * @var int
  */
protected $uidLocal;

/**
 * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\ResourceInterface $originalResource
 */
public function setOriginalResource(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\ResourceInterface $originalResource)
{
    $this->originalResource = $originalResource;
    $this->uidLocal = (int)$originalResource->getOriginalFile()->getUid();
}

/**
 * @return \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\FileReference
 */
public function getOriginalResource()
{
    if ($this->originalResource === null) {
        $this->originalResource = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\ResourceFactory::getInstance()->getFileReferenceObject($this->getUid());
    }

    return $this->originalResource;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you have an instance of `TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference` then you can use `getOriginalResource()` to get the wrapped `TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\FileReference`. If you need the referenced file, you can then use `getOriginalFile()`. Thus as a chained call:

```
$file = $fileReference->getOriginalResource()->getOriginalFile();
```

Notice that you don't have to use the `ResourceFactory` yourself in all of this, this is taken care of internally.

Answer (score 0):

Work form me.

You can find or get file refernce uid using custom query.

**In Controller :**

```
$uid = $yourObject->getUid();
$fileReference = $this->yourRepository->getFileReferenceObject($uid);
```

**In Repository**

```
public function getFileRefernceHeaderLogo($uid){
        $query = $this->createQuery();
        $queryString = "SELECT *
                            FROM sys_file_reference
                                WHERE deleted = 0 
                                        AND hidden = 0 
                                            AND tablenames='your_table_name'
                                                AND fieldname='your_field_name'
                                                    AND uid_foreign =".$uid;

        $query->statement($queryString);
        return $res = $query->execute(true);            
    }
```

**In Controller**

```
$fileRefUid = $fileReference[0]['uid'];
```

Here you can get uid of file reference table.It is long process.

You can also get sys_file table uid for getFileObject.like,

```
$sys_file_uid = $fileReference[0]['uid_local'];
```